# CUDA substituting __syncthreads instead of __threadfence() difference

Tags: cuda

I have copied the below code from NVIDIA manual Eg: for `__threadfence()`. Why they have 
used `__threadfence()` in the below code. I think using `__syncthreads()` instead of 
`__threadfence()` will give you the same result.

Can someone explain the difference between `__syncthreads()` and `__threadfence()` calls?

```
__device__ unsigned int count = 0;
__shared__ bool isLastBlockDone;

__global__ void sum(const float* array, unsigned int N,float* result)
{
    // Each block sums a subset of the input array
    float partialSum = calculatePartialSum(array, N);

    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        // Thread 0 of each block stores the partial sum
        // to global memory
        result[blockIdx.x] = partialSum;

        // Thread 0 makes sure its result is visible to
        // all other threads
        __threadfence();

        // Thread 0 of each block signals that it is done
        unsigned int value = atomicInc(&count, gridDim.x);

        // Thread 0 of each block determines if its block is
        // the last block to be done
        isLastBlockDone = (value == (gridDim.x - 1));
    }

    // Synchronize to make sure that each thread reads
    // the correct value of isLastBlockDone
    __syncthreads();

    if (isLastBlockDone) 
    {
        // The last block sums the partial sums
        // stored in result[0 .. gridDim.x-1]
        float totalSum = calculateTotalSum(result);

        if (threadIdx.x == 0)
        {
            // Thread 0 of last block stores total sum
            // to global memory and resets count so that
            // next kernel call works properly
            result[0] = totalSum;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

In terms of shared memory `__syncthreads()` is simply stronger than `__threadfence()`. Regarding global memory - those are two different things.

- `__threadfence_block()` stalls current thread until all writes to shared memory are visible to other threads from the same block. It prevents the compiler from optimising by caching shared memory writes in registers. It does *not* synchronise the threads and it is not necessary for all threads to actually reach this instruction.
- `__threadfence()` stalls current thread until all writes to shared and global memory are visible to all other threads.
- `__syncthreads()` must be reached by all threads from the block (e.g. no divergent `if` statements) and ensures that the code preceding the instruction is executed *before* the instructions following it, for all threads in the block.

In your particular case, the `__threadfence()` instruction is used to make sure that writes to global array `result` are visible to everyone. `__syncthreads()` would merely synchronise threads in the current block only, without enforcing the global memory writes for other block. What is more, at that point in the code you are inside an `if` branch, only one thread is executing that code; using `__syncthreads()` would result in an undefined behaviour of the GPU, most likely leading to complete desynchronisation of the kernel.

Check out the following chapters in the CUDA C Programming Guide:

- 3.2.2 "Shared Memory" - the example of matrix multiplication
- 5.4.3 "Synchronization Instruction"
- B.2.5 "volatile"
- B.5 "Memory Fence Functions"

Comment: AFAIK Using `__syncthreads()` inside an `if` branch which splits warp will lead to deadlocking, not to desynchronization.

Comment: Formally, it leads to "undefined behavior". You may be right that warp-divergent `if` may lead to deadlock. But even if you have warp-convergent, but block-divergent `if`, one warp may stop at different `__syncthreads` than another, as they are indistinguishable (at least on some GPUs), leading to desynchronization. Bottom line: bad things happen; don't do it.